# Python check if value in tuple fails with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I've got a function that returns a tuple, and I need to check if a specific element is in the tuple. I don't know types of elements will be in the tuple, but I know that I want an exact match. For example, I want

```
1 in (1, [0, 6], 0) --> True
1 in ([1], 0, 6]) --> False
```

This should be really straightforward, right? I just check `1 in tuple_output_from_function`.

This breaks if there is a numpy array as an element in the tuple

```
import numpy as np
s = tuple((2, [0, 6], 1))
4 in s --> False

t = tuple((2, np.arrary([0, 6]), 1))
4 in t --> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I expect the second case to return False because 4 is not in the tuple. Even if it were in the array, I would still expect False. I can do `0 in t[1]` without error. Why does this break, and how can I make my check robust to it without *assuming* that there will be a numpy array or having to check for it explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It breaks because if you `in` operator, Python under the hood is using the equality operator (`==`).

Consider this:

```py
t = (2, np.array([0, 6]), 1)
v = 1

print(v in t)
```

Python checks each value in the tuple `t` for equality. For numpy array the operation `1 == np.array([0, 6])` is another boolean array `[False False]`. Python then checks if this result is truthy, which throws the exception you see.

You can use `any()` and check if the current value you check is the type of the value is `int`:

```
t = (2, np.array([0, 6]), 1)
v = 1

x = any(v == i for i in t if isinstance(i, int))
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
True
```

Comment: Perhaps a useful enhancement is `isinstance(i, numbers.Number)` ? Then you can replicate the native behaviour where `4 in (4.0, 5.0)` is True.